# Ignore forAll assertions for endpoints tested in details

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm using gatling for perftests of multiple rest endpoints. Most of them should end in the meantime of 2,5s, but there are exceptions. The following setup tests the meantime of `"some group" / "some endpoint"` for both thresholds (2,5s and 5s):

```
setUp(
  scn.inject(
    constantConcurrentUsers(10) during (15 minutes)
  )
)
  .assertions(
    forAll.responseTime.mean.lt(2500),
    details("some group" / "some endpoint").responseTime.mean.lt(5000),
  )
  .protocols(httpsProtocol)
```

This is a simplified code, there are more metrics tested and more exceptions to the global thresholds.

**Question**: How to disable `forAll` for exceptions tested in `details` or how to achieve such a behavior in this scenario (meantime of `"some group" / "some endpoint"` should be less than 5s and of all others - 2,5s)?

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not possible. You'd have to list all individual request types instead of using forAll.